# Will lseek SEEK_END get the accurate size before fsync?

Tags: c, linux

After I called `pwrite()`, I called a `lseek()` with SEEK_END before `fsync()` or `close()`. Assume the file is 1M before my `pwrite()` and 2M after it, which size will my `lseek()` get? 1M or 2M?

In addition, am I suppose to get the same value for that lseek() with SEEK_END if I call this function in different parallel workers?

Comment: Use `fstat()` to get the file size.

Comment: @Shawn I'm coding based on PostgreSQL and they use lseek for counting the number of block. I don't think I can change that :P

Comment: You can easily test it yourself.

Comment: @0___________ Newbie to linux. Can I control the manner of `pwrite()`? I think the data may be in the buffer or on the disk, and i cannot control it....

Comment: Whether the data is in a buffer or flushed to disk shouldn't affect where SEEK_END takes you, even in different threads/processes. I believe fsync() flushes the buffer to disk, so you do have some control. Someone please say so if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: Even fsync'ing doesn't guarantee that the data has been successfully recorded on your persistent storage device so that it would survive a sudden power loss or component failure for example as sometimes they cache the writes in on-device memory. If you're coding a DB, you might want to look deeper into this stuff.